# zk grid template "model", refers to specific element

Tags: java, zk

I have grid with template "model" which takes a list. Each element of list has unique name.

How to refer to specific element by name? Because I want to set that row to be visible or not based on certain condition.

Comment: can you post the part of the zul?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be row_name.attribute, in this case:
rowName.visible = condition (true/false)

Answer (score 0):

You can set HTML attributes on ZK elements to be able to refer to them by name but it is a bit of a "hack" because that is not the purpose of how ZK is intended to function.